# Automapper over the converters

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the code, which use the userClass converters. I want to do the same thing using automapper. How to rewrite the code?

```
public static ClaimIdentityView ConvertToClaimIdentityView(this ClaimsIdentity Identity)
{
    ClaimIdentityView result = new ClaimIdentityView()
    {
        Name = Identity.Name,
        NameClaimType = Identity.NameClaimType,
        AuthenticationType = (AuthenticationTypeEnum)EnumStringValue.Parse(typeof(AuthenticationTypeEnum), Identity.AuthenticationType), 
        RoleClaimType = Identity.RoleClaimType
    };
    foreach (Claim item in Identity.Claims)
        result.ClaimViewList.Add(item.ConvertToClaimView());
    return result;
}
 public static ClaimView ConvertToClaimView(this Claim Claim)
{
     return new ClaimView()
     {
        Type = Claim.Type,
        Value = Claim.Value,
        ValueType = Claim.ValueType
     };
}
```

And the second class (the first one is from System.Security.Claims; namespace):

```
public class ClaimIdentityView
{
    public ClaimIdentityView()
    {
        ClaimViewList = new List<ClaimView>();
    }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public AuthenticationTypeEnum AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public IList<ClaimView> ClaimViewList { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NameClaimType { get; set; }
    public string RoleClaimType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mappings would look like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ClaimsIdentity, ClaimIdentityView>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ClaimViewList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Claims))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.AuthenticationType,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (AuthenticationTypeEnum) 
        EnumStringValue.Parse(typeof (AuthenticationTypeEnum), src.AuthenticationType)));

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Claim, ClaimView>();
```

Example mapping code:

```
var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
var view = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClaimsIdentity, ClaimIdentityView>(claimIdentity);
```

This test would then pass:

```
var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
// realistically the current account will have claims, but..
claimIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Type", "Value")); 
var view = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClaimsIdentity, ClaimIdentityView>(claimIdentity);

Assert.IsTrue(view.ClaimViewList.Count > 0);
```

Comment: Yep, but how to fill the ClaimViewList during mapping ClaimView? Does automapper support delegate or something?

Comment: The ClaimViewList is a list of ClaimViews, and AutoMapper knows how to map a Claim to a ClaimView, and how to map a list to a list. I forgot to add the bit that tells AutoMapper how to link the properties as they have different names, I've edited the answer.

Comment: I mean that you have missed the cycle:
    foreach (Claim item in Identity.Claims)
        result.ClaimViewList.Add(item.ConvertToClaimView());
So, I need to do something like this:
/.../.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.ClaimViewList.Concat(src.Claims));
But I don't know how to make it correctly.

Comment: No, I haven't missed that: the claims are mapped to the view. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: I don't understand how it possible then.

Comment: 1. Automapper has been told to use the source property "Claims" for the destination property "ClaimsViewList" 2. Automapper has been told how to map a Claim to a ClaimView 3. Automapper handles lists automatically 4. Automapper therefore maps the claims the the ClaimViewList when mapping the ClaimsIdentity to the ClaimsIdentityView.

Comment: it means that automapper add elements to a collection if he knows how to map "object type" of collection?

Comment: Shall I create a new Map for backside convertation? From ClaimidentityView to ClaimIdentity?

Comment: If you need to map back, then yes.

Comment: When I try to map back Mapper.CreateMap<ClaimView, Claim> I have an «Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping» exception. I've post my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994261/missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping-after-auto-code-generation